# Select a date with Material Datepicker with Cypress

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress

I'm implementing some tests using Cypress for an application implemented with Angular and Angular Material.

For some of my screens, I have some forms with date pickers and I want to fill these fields in my tests using the picker not using the `type` method of Cypress.

So I need to make things generic:

- Open the picker (it's simple leveraging the `click` method of Cypress)
- Select the correct month (so I have to iterate over months until the correct month is found)
- Select the correct day of the month (I think it's simple too leveraging the `click` method of Cypress)
- Define all these processing as a command or something to use at several parts in tests

So my questions are:

- How to implement `while` into Cypress?
- How to interact with an Angular Material Datepicker the best way within Cypress tests?
- What is the best generic thing of Cypress to use (commands)?

Thanks very much for your help,
Thierry

Comment: **How to implement while** - in theory you should know the current state and new state, so while should not be necessary. For example, current month is Jan & you want to test moving to Jun, that's 5 clicks right.

Comment: **How to interact with an Angular Material Datepicker** - the way the user will interact with it, directly click on `cy.contains('.mat-calendar-body-cell-content', targetDate)` or `cy.type({rightarrow})` or both depending on how fussy you want to be. But are you testing the Datepicker itself? Why not directly enter the date?

Comment: @AloysiusParker thanks for your answer! The application directly opens the picker when clicking on the field. That's why I wanted to simulate the date selection through the picker.

Comment: @AloysiusParker what do you mean by " you should know the current state and new state"? I mean how this allows us not to use a loop...

Answer (score 1):

**Select the correct month (so I have to iterate over months until the correct month is found)**

This sounds something like (pseudo code)

```js
while (cy.contains('#mat-calendar-button-0', targetMonth)) {
  cy.get('button.mat-calendar-next-button').click()
}
```

but it won't work because Cypress commands are queued and run async to the `while` loop. (also the return is not useable in this way).

There are many questions asking for conditional testing, most answers end up being ***in-elegant branching code*** that does what Cypress terms 'backflips' to set a closure variable that controls the while loop.

But if you know that the page starts with (say) month 'Jan' and you want to set month 'Jun' you can use a simpler `for` loop which does not rely on page testing to finish

```js
// advance 5 months
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                        // queues up 5 clicks
  cy.get('button.mat-calendar-next-button').click()
}
```

If you really must use conditional testing (say the next button was flaky and did not always respond to click), you would use a synchronous jQuery expression to control the loop, something like

```js
while (!Cypress.$(`#mat-calendar-button-0:contains(${targetMonth}).length) {
  cy.get('button.mat-calendar-next-button').click()
}
```

but the problem is you loose Cypress' auto-retry that's built in to (most) commands. Any async code happening after clicks, even animation, can make the test flaky.